# netplan configuration not active -- ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, netplan

trying to set up a fixed IP address on one of two NIC. I try using netplan. Not working at all.

Not an expert on this, I am out of my wits and ready to roll back to some other way (networkd). Maybe someone has a useful advice in any direction. Any help/ comment greatly appreciated !

**(A) PROBLEM:**

1) after boot, enp2s0 has no ip4 address assigned

2) this also cannot be achieved by

```
 - :~$ sudo netplan generate
 - :~$ sudo netplan apply
```

as a side note, tried changing interface names previously which also takes no effect.

**(B) SYSTEM CONFIG:**

```
:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

This down here remains completely unchanged, despite whatever I try with netplan (just omitting addresses for privacy):

```
:~$ ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether --omitted-- brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether --omitted-- brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.117/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic enp3s0
       valid_lft 1814043sec preferred_lft 1814043sec
    inet6 --omitted-- scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 604790sec preferred_lft 86390sec
    inet6 --omitted-- scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Netplan seems to be the "official" setup:

```
:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

This is my netplan config, it seems to validate, as netplan invocations don't throw errors. there is only one yaml file.

```
:~$ cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml 
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [217.0.43.65, 217.237.149.225]
        search: []
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

**(C) FINDINGS/INVESTIGATIONS:**

I looked at this stuff, but to no avail

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083390/netplan-apply-does-not-change-the-ip-address

https://netplan.io/troubleshooting

netplan seems to have generated what I wanted:

```
:~$ cat /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp2s0.network 
[Match]
Name=enp2s0

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=192.168.1.1/24
DNS=217.0.43.65
DNS=217.237.149.225
```

Note the generate output - anything obvious ?

```
:~$ sudo netplan --debug generate
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:2523): DEBUG: 10:24:20.181: Processing input file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..
** (generate:2523): DEBUG: 10:24:20.182: starting new processing pass
** (generate:2523): DEBUG: 10:24:20.182: enp3s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:2523): DEBUG: 10:24:20.182: Configuration is valid
** (generate:2523): DEBUG: 10:24:20.182: enp2s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:2523): DEBUG: 10:24:20.182: Configuration is valid
** (generate:2523): DEBUG: 10:24:20.182: Generating output files..
** (generate:2523): DEBUG: 10:24:20.182: NetworkManager: definition enp2s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:2523): DEBUG: 10:24:20.182: NetworkManager: definition enp3s0 is not for us (backend 1)
```

Please look at these outputs, they seem to carry the only hints:

```
:~$ sudo netplan --debug apply
** (generate:2528): DEBUG: 10:25:18.755: Processing input file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..
** (generate:2528): DEBUG: 10:25:18.755: starting new processing pass
** (generate:2528): DEBUG: 10:25:18.755: enp3s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:2528): DEBUG: 10:25:18.755: Configuration is valid
** (generate:2528): DEBUG: 10:25:18.755: enp2s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:2528): DEBUG: 10:25:18.755: Configuration is valid
** (generate:2528): DEBUG: 10:25:18.755: Generating output files..
** (generate:2528): DEBUG: 10:25:18.755: NetworkManager: definition enp2s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:2528): DEBUG: 10:25:18.755: NetworkManager: definition enp3s0 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, restarting networkd
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:enp2s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:enp3s0 not found in {'enp2s0': {'dhcp4': False, 'addresses': ['192.168.1.1/24'], 'nameservers': {'addresses': ['217.0.43.65', '217.237.149.225'], 'search': []}}}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.1/24
      dhcp4: false
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 217.0.43.65
        - 217.237.149.225
        search: []
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
  vlans: {}
  wifis: {}

DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG:device enp3s0 operstate is up, not changing
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: wlp1s0
DEBUG:{}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp2s0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp3s0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for wlp1s0
```

Note it first says "netplan generated networkd configuration changed..." but then in next line "no netplan generated NM configuration exists". Sounds like some networkd config is still active ?

Also, it seems to have some problem on application level (syntax accepted) with the yaml: enp2s0 not found in {}, also in line just below that. But why ?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution or workaround to this problem? I'm having the exact issue with completely same behavior.

Comment: Looking further into this, when I modified /etc/systemd/network/10-netplan-*.network and changed "Match" to use "Name" rather then MAC address it started working for me.